# What version did WordPress stop using MD5?

Tags: passwords, wordpress

I've been trying to find a version of which WordPress stopped using MD5 and started using the Portable PHP password hashing framework. I've been trying to search for a while and found nothing, the closest thing I can find is "WordPress used to use MD5" but I can't pinpoint a version.

If anyone can remember, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to find these things is often to check the source.

If you go to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress) and search for the password hashing implementation you'll find it in [`wp-includes/pluggable.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L2265). Then it's just a matter of looking back through [history](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blame/master/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L2265) to find the [commit](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commit/07e337adcf43c91a71213085ba619646affe4c0d) that made the change. The oldest version that commit is tagged with is 2.5.

This is further confirmed by checking the [release notes](https://wordpress.org/news/2008/03/wordpress-25-brecker/) for that version:

> Salted passwords — we now use the phpass library to stretch and salt all passwords stored in the database, which makes brute-forcing them impractical.